# Want to add standardoutput of process in Listview

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I am running a bat file from process and want to add standard output in Listview for which I wrote code below

```
 public void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(outLine.Data);                
            WriteInListBox(outLine.Data.ToString());
        }
    }

    public delegate void WriteHandler(string s);
    private void WriteInListBox(string text)
    { 
        if (this.logText.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new WriteHandler(WriteInListBox), new Object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
             this.logText.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine + text);
        }
    }
```

Now it try to write line in listview first time then it never comes in WriteInListBox function and hangs